# Сортировка коллекции по заданному параметру

Tags: c#, сортировка

Имеется класс

```
public class human:IComparable<human>
{
    double salary;

    public double GetSalaryDollars()
    {
        return salary * 3;
    }

    int IComparable<human>.CompareTo(human other)
    {
        return salary.CompareTo(other.salary);
    }
}
```

Имеется некая коллекции объектов данного класса (инициализацию опустил)

```
List<human> mas = new List<human>();
```

Таким образом `mas.Sort();` я отсортирую свою коллекцию по параметру `salary`, т.е. по-умолчанию, т.к. я так реализовал интерфейс `IComparable`.
Вопрос, как производить сортировку по заданному параметру ?
Т.е. если я хочу отсортировать по параметру `salary`, я бы писал как-то так:
`mas.Sort(salary);`

Если бы я хотел сортировать по параметру `GetSalaryDollars()`, я бы писал как-то так:
`mas.Sort(GetSalaryDollars());`

Одним словом, что бы моя сортировка могла быть гибкая, что бы я сам выбирал по какому параметру сортировать. Как это возможно осуществить? Может быть как-то с помощью лямбда-выражений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сортировки по произвольному параметру используйте вариант метода [`List<T>.Sort Method (Comparison<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
mas.Sort(
    delegate(human x, human y)
    {
        return x.GetSalaryDollars().CompareTo(y.GetSalaryDollars());
    });
```

Вместо делегата можете использовать [лямбда-выражение](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx), но это уже вкусовщина:

```
mas.Sort(
    (human x, human y) =>
    {
        return x.GetSalaryDollars().CompareTo(y.GetSalaryDollars());
    });
```

Преимущество такого метода в том, что вам не надо реализовывать интерфейс IComparable в вашей структуре. Вообще в коде делегата вы можете использовать любой код и любые данные, в том числе и не входящие в данные структуры `human`. Это же удобно использовать для регулирования направления сортировки. Например, в качестве данных для сортировки можете написать:

```
//Список избранных.
HashSet<hunam> chosenOnes = ...;

//Направление сортировки.
bool chosenOnesDown = true;

mas.Sort(
    delegate(human x, human y)
    {
        int result;

        if (chosenOnes.Contains(x))
        {
            result = -1;
        }
        else if (chosenOnes.Contains(y))
        {
            result = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            result = 0;
        }

        //Используем внешний флаг для управления направлением сортировки.
        if (chosenOnesDown)
        {
            result *= -1;
        }

        return result;
    });
```

Так "избранные" всплывут наверх списка или пойдут на дно в зависимости от значения флага `chosenOnesDown`, в то время как сами `human` не знают, кто избранный, а кто нет.

Если для сравнения структур хочется использовать внутренние данные структуры, недоступные снаружи, то можно выставить из структуры соответствующий метод:

```
public class human
{
    //Внутренние данные.
    private double salary;

    //Публичная реализация сравнения структур, расположенная внутри класса,
    //имеет доступ к внутренним данным и методам.
    public static int CompareByDollarSalary(human x, human y)
    {
        return x.GetSalaryDollars().CompareTo(y.GetSalaryDollars());
    }

    //Внутренние методы.
    private double GetSalaryDollars()
    {
        return salary * 3;
    }
}

//Для сортировки достаточно указать любой метод с соответствующей сигнатурой.
mas.Sort(human.CompareByDollarSalary);
```

Comment: А если, к примеру, поля , по которым будет производиться сортировка - закрытые, возможно ли реализацию сортировки реализовать внутри класса?

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин Да, возможно, сейчас дополню.

Comment: @PyrejkeeПурешкин Дополнил.

Comment: Очень развёрнуто, благодарю!